# Reload a UITableView with select objects from a NSArray depending on cell selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have a ViewController with a `tableView`, and I also have the following `NSArray` called `dag`:

```
[{"ID":67,"ParentsID":0,"Title":"Products"},
{"ID":68,"ParentsID":67,"Title":"Class A"},
{"ID":69,"ParentsID":67,"Title":"Class B"},
{"ID":70,"ParentsID":68,"Title":"Recurrent"},
{"ID":71,"ParentsID":68,"Title":"Non Recurrent"},
{"ID":72,"ParentsID":70,"Title":"Basic"},
{"ID":73,"ParentsID":70,"Title":"Advanced"},
{"ID":74,"ParentsID":71,"Title":"Incentives"}]
```

I'm already able to use the `tableView` to display the Title of the items with Key `"ParentsID"` equal to `"0"`. In other words, I am loading the table with:

```
"Products" //from `{"ID":67,"ParentsID":0,"Title":"Products"}`.
```

Now, when I select the row "Products" in the tableView, I would like the tableView to reload and show the items whose `"ParentsID"` is equal to the `"ID"` of that "Products" item (67).
i.e: Selecting "Products" will load :

```
"Class A"  //from {"ID":68,"ParentsID":67,"Title":"Class A"}, and
"Class B"  //from {"ID":69,"ParentsID":67,"Title":"Class B"}
           //because their ParentsID is equal to the ID of "Products"
```

Then I would like this behaviour to continue when selecting either "Class A" or "Class B", and so on.

How can I do this?

I would think that I would have to instantiate a new tableview in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` taking as a reference the value's ID, but I have no idea how to do it or if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: assuming you have a navigation controller, you can insatiate the new controller and push it onto the nav controllers stack

Comment: or if you don't and it will be a one off, you could present that child view controller.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I do have a Navigation Controller, how can I instantiate the new one and push it onto the stack? could you please provide some sample code on this?

Comment: I am barely able to follow your storyline.  What do you mean by selecting the row "Products"?  How many rows are there?  The number of the array count?  What is the name of the array?  Is it really a simple array or an NSMutableArray with an NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: @TBlue Initially, the tableView has only one row showing "Products". When I click on it, I would like to load the tableView with 2 rows showing "Class A" on the first one and "Class B" on the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general approach to making level-by-level hierarchy views with tables and navigation controllers:

1. Create a `UITableViewDataSource` class that stores your `NSArray` and an `int parentId`
2. Add a `UINavigationController` to the screen where you would like to display the hierarchy
3. Create a controller that embeds `UITableView` for your table
4. Add an initializer to the above controller that takes a data source defined in step 1
5. Provide a handler to the table item selection event.

In the event handler from step 5, get the ID of the current row, instantiate a new data source for that ID from step 1, then instantiate a new view controller from step 3 by calling the initializer from step 4, and push the newly created controller onto the stack of the navigation controller from step 2.

Comment: What do you mean by a `UITableViewDataSource` class? A sub-class of `NSObject` or `NSData` to store the `NSArray` and `int parentID`?

Comment: @JuanAndres I mean your implementation of the [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), i.e. the class that provides the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods. These are often combined with the view controller when there is only one table to display, but I did not want to make this assumption for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two viewControllers inside `NavigationController` for your scenarios, on `firstViewController` you can have UITableView having all products within it, when you select any product you could push a new view which would be your `secondViewController`, and second view could also have a `UITableView` or anything depending on how you want to to show the data selected from the row.
it will look something like this on `firstViewController`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  SecondViewController  *secondViewController=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

  // save the selected Row data and in some string of secondViewController
  secondViewController.dataString=[self.idList objectAtIndex:row]; 

 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

}
```